# Why Etherscan is reporting negative token balances?

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, balances

I am wondering if its possible a holder to have negative balances as reported by Etherscan. Bellow are the links for the cases that I spotted:

- KICK token holder `0xc12d1c73ee7dc3615ba4e37e4abfdbddfa38907e`: https://etherscan.io/token/0xc12d1c73ee7dc3615ba4e37e4abfdbddfa38907e?a=0xc12d1c73ee7dc3615ba4e37e4abfdbddfa38907e#tokenAnalytics
- WETH token holder `0x76481caa104b5f6bccb540dae4cefaf1c398ebea`: https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2?a=0x76481caa104b5f6bccb540dae4cefaf1c398ebea#tokenAnalytics

How reliable is for applications that keep track of historical ERC20 token balances based on just ERC20's `Transfer` events and querying `balanceOf` for a given address? Does make sense to have negative balances at some point of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Etherscan is a closed source block explorer so we can speculate only about their behavior.

From [WETH contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#code) no transfer event is generated when minting new tokens.

```
function deposit() public payable {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);  // <--- Desposit event it is not Transfer
}
```

From the [ERC20 specs](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) there's no standard event for minting tokens. Most projects use `Transfer(address(0), target, amount)`.

If Etherscan relies only on `Transfer` events it might have wrong accounting when a contract mint their own tokens.